# Python 3.10 returning 7 same records instead of one specified

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python and for some reason print summary returns all records, 7 times per record instead of returning all records. I'm running Python3.10, what would be the cause of this? My code is down below:

```
record_data_list = []


def read_file():
    infile = open('RECORD_DATA.txt')
    for row in infile:
        start = 0
        string_builder = []
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            for index in range(len(row)):
                if row[index] == ',' or index == len(row) - 1:
                    string_builder.append(row[start:index])
                    start = index + 1
                    record_data_list.append(string_builder)
    infile.close()


def print_summary():
    for i in record_data_list:
        print(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6])



read_file()
print_menu()
```

My RECORD_DATA.txt:

```
#Listing showing sample record details
#ARTIST, TITLE, GENRE, PLAY LENGTH, CONDITION, STOCK, COST
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, English Suites, Classical, LP, Good, 1, 5.99
Harty, An Irish Symphony, Classical, EP, As New, 1, 14.99
John Martyn, One World, Pop, LP, As New, 1, 14.99
Rush, Signals, Rock, LP, Very Good, 1, 10.49
Courtney Pine, Underground, Jazz, LP, Acceptable, 1, 8.99
Peter Gabriel, Secret World, Pop, LP, Very Good, 2, 7.99
John Cleese, The Screwtape Letters, Spoken Word, LP, Good, 1, 12.49
Beethoven, The Pastoral Symphony, Classical, EP, Good, 1, 7.49
Glen Miller, In the Mood, Jazz, 45, Acceptable, 3, 5.49
John Tavener, Goode Companie Awaites, Classical, 78, Acceptable, 1, 24.99
The Beatles, Maxwell's Silver Hammer, Pop, 45, Acceptable, 2, 5.49
```

Intended output is:

```
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
```

...

What is being output is:

```
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Queen, Greatest Hits, Rock, LP, Very Good, 2, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
Bach, Mass in B Minor, Classical, LP, Acceptable, 1, 10.49
```

and so on..

Comment: Can you edit the question to have the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include the intended output and the observed output.

Comment: By the way, every time you call `read_file()` it will add a bunch of new items to `record_data_list` in addition to everything that was already there.

Comment: hi thanks for help, i edited for intended outputs and what im getting instead

Comment: i edited the code to minimal required for problem reproduce

Comment: the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module might be of interest to you

Comment: i will take a look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with this clause:

```
for index in range(len(row)):
    if row[index] == ',' or index == len(row) - 1:
        string_builder.append(row[start:index])
        start = index + 1
        record_data_list.append(string_builder)
```

This is executed on each row, and it looks through every character in that row. If the character is a comma or the end of the row, it appends the string builder to the record data list. Thus, since you have six commas and one end of line you're getting the record seven times in your final list. What you probably want to do is only append after this for loop is complete.

```
for index in range(len(row)):
    if row[index] == ',' or index == len(row) - 1:
        string_builder.append(row[start:index])
        start = index + 1
record_data_list.append(string_builder)
```

Comment: thank you for helping out, your answer did the trick! hours of consuming lesson learnt